# Replace two object property values and create new array

Tags: javascript

I need to take an existing array of objects, replace the names depending on two different id's, and create a new array. I also need to make sure all other properties don't change.

My JSON:

```
const legendData = [{

     "assetManagerId": 11,
     "name": "AIM Derivatives",
     "fileTypeId": 1,
 {
     "assetManagerId": 11,
     "name": "AIM Derivatives",
     "fileTypeId": 2,
 },
 {
     "assetManagerId": 8,
     "name": "Barings",
     "fileTypeId": 2,
 },
 {
     "assetManagerId": 5,
     "name": "BlackRock",
     "fileTypeId": 1,
}]
```

I need the AIM Derivatives names to change to the below, however, keep the rest the same.

```
const = legendData[{
     "assetManagerId": 11,
     "name": "AIM Derivatives ODIN",
     "fileTypeId": 1,
 {
     "assetManagerId": 11,
     "name": "AIM Derivatives CMF",
     "fileTypeId": 2,
 },
 {
     "assetManagerId": 8,
     "name": "Barings",
     "fileTypeId": 2,
 },
 {
     "assetManagerId": 5,
     "name": "BlackRock",
     "fileTypeId": 1,
}]
```

I got halfway with my code below, however, don't know how to combine both. The below only changes if the fileTypeId is 1 but not 2.

```
const newArr = legendData.map(item => item.assetManagerId === 11 && item.fileTypeId === 1? {
            ...item, name: "AIM Derivatives ODIN"
            } : item)

console.log(newArr)
```

Comment: *"My JSON"* JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON. What you have there is an array of objects.

Comment: you can just check if the prop exists `item.assetManagerId && item.fileTypeId`

Comment: You have not included the rules for which `assetManagerId` and `fileTypeId` values cause what modifications to `name`.

Comment: Since there are three possible outcomes, I wouldn't use the conditional operator for this. For clarity, I'd use `if (/*...*/) {/*...*/} else if (/*...*/) {/*...*/} else {/*...*/}` You have code correctly handling ODIN. Do the same thing in the `else if` for CMF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for `fileTypeId === 1` and `item.fileTypeId === 2` seperately like:

```js
const legendData = [{assetManagerId:11,name:"AIM Derivatives",fileTypeId:1},{assetManagerId:11,name:"AIM Derivatives",fileTypeId:2},{assetManagerId:8,name:"Barings",fileTypeId:2},{assetManagerId:5,name:"BlackRock",fileTypeId:1}];

const newArr = legendData.map(item => {
  if(item.assetManagerId === 11 && item.fileTypeId === 1){
    return {...item, name: "AIM Derivatives ODIN"}
  } else if (item.assetManagerId === 11 && item.fileTypeId === 2){
    return {...item, name: "AIM Derivatives CMF"}
  } else {
    return item
  }
})

console.log(newArr)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Or using single expression like:

```js
const legendData = [{assetManagerId:11,name:"AIM Derivatives",fileTypeId:1},{assetManagerId:11,name:"AIM Derivatives",fileTypeId:2},{assetManagerId:8,name:"Barings",fileTypeId:2},{assetManagerId:5,name:"BlackRock",fileTypeId:1}];

const newArr = legendData.map(item => item.assetManagerId === 11 ? {
  ...item,
  name: item.fileTypeId === 1 ? "AIM Derivatives ODIN" :
    (item.fileTypeId === 2 ? "AIM Derivatives CMF" : item.name)
} : item)

console.log(newArr)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to nest the loop as so:

```js
const newArr = legendData.map(item => (item.assetManagerId === 11)? (item.fileTypeId === 1? {
            ...item, name: "AIM Derivatives ODIN"
            } : item.fileTypeId === 2? {
            ...item, name: "AIM Derivatives CMF"
            } : item ) : item)

console.log(newArr)
```

(probably use a standard if-else so it's a lot cleaner)

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd be tempted to use a lookup:

```
const suffixes = ["", "ODIN", "CMF"];
const newArr = legendData.map(item => {
    const suffix = item.assetManagerId === 11 && suffixes[item.fileTypeId];
    if (suffix) {
        return {...item, name: `${item.name} ${suffix}`};
    }
    return item;
});
```

Live Example:

```js
const legendData = [{

     "assetManagerId": 11,
     "name": "AIM Derivatives",
     "fileTypeId": 1,
},
 {
     "assetManagerId": 11,
     "name": "AIM Derivatives",
     "fileTypeId": 2,
 },
 {
     "assetManagerId": 8,
     "name": "Barings",
     "fileTypeId": 2,
 },
 {
     "assetManagerId": 5,
     "name": "BlackRock",
     "fileTypeId": 1,
}];

const suffixes = ["", "ODIN", "CMF"];
const newArr = legendData.map(item => {
    const suffix = item.assetManagerId === 11 && suffixes[item.fileTypeId];
    if (suffix) {
        return {...item, name: `${item.name} ${suffix}`};
    }
    return item;
});

console.log(newArr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Or if you prefer the conditional operator:

```
const suffixes = ["", "ODIN", "CMF"];
const newArr = legendData.map(item => {
    const suffix = item.assetManagerId === 11 && suffixes[item.fileTypeId];
    return suffix ? {...item, name: `${item.name} ${suffix}`} : item;
});
```

The lookup can be an array as shown, an object, or a `Map`.